# Delete list of sign-in names from dropdown menu on log-in page

Tags: macbook-pro, google-chrome

I'm using Google Chrome and whenever I want to login to a forum site, a dropdown with a list of misspelled and wrong names gets displayed as soon as I click on the username field.

How do I delete the list of the different usernames, leaving only the corect one there?

Comment: Stack Exchange works best when there is one question, one answer. I've tidied your post to the first question, though we still need clarification of which browser you are using. If you want to post your second question separately, please go ahead.

Comment: Don't worry. I asked this question elsewhere, and received an immediate and effective reply. Thanks anyway.